# Error: Workbook file name or sheet name to long, "file" has more than 54 characters

Tags: r, vba, excel, rexcel

I've implemented some machine learning function into Excel, therefore, I used the RExcel add-in. Now I'm trying to predict classes based on certain input data. This input data is written in Excel. A macro read this input data and transforms it to R, which classifies this data. I have to classify 3000 record which all contain 4 variables.

In case I use a small (n<999) dataset, the function works fine. But in case of a dataset with n>1000 RExcel give the following error:

```
Rexcel Error 1301
in module RExcel.Arrays

Workbook file name or sheet name to long,
"[file.xlsm]sheet1" has more than 54 characters.
```

I read the data in with the following comment:

```
    private sub commandbutton.click()
        Dim test As Range, 
        Set test = Range(CalcProbs.testData)
        .....
        call Classifydata(test)
    end sub

Function classifydata(test as Range)
    ....
    rinterface.PutDataframe "test", test
    ....
end function
```

with CalcProbs.testData as refEdit.

Does anybody know wheter the function rinterface.PutDataFrame only works for a limited size of data, or is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have already found the problem.
I saved the Excel file with a shorter name and it works perfect.